# SoftKeyboard issue

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, virtual-keyboard

I am working on softkeyboard.

My issues are below.

1. How to get current position of cursor in text(EditText).
2. How to get total length of value in text(EditText).
3. If EditText is multi-line then get current line of cursor in text(EditText).

If you want see my code then see this [softkeyboard's link](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SoftKeyboard/index.html). I am following this code.

Answer (score 1):

You should put textwatcher event in edittext this is the event is execute when user type a character (any in put by key board).
In your case when user type a single character in edittext you got hole text then get length of this text it is your cursor position and total length of value in text.
according to your third  question you have all the text written in edit text using above method then you convert all the text in ascii value then compare every character with 13(it is the ascii value of enter in keyboard )and increase counter of line when it condition true using this you find no of line in edit text. i am giving a example for you how to put text watcher in edittext you change in this code and convert it according to your condition.

```
ed.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
            }

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {

                textlength = ed.getText().length();
                );

            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks ShowHide, but I think you didn't read clearly my question. Actually I am working on softkeyboard and all things are working in service. and so how i can get current EditText in service..